# Can not access public instances from other class

Tags: java

I have two instances: socket and packet as public in main class but I can not access them from other class, and they are in the same package.

I get: cannot find symbol for both of them.

```
    public class enviar extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {    
           socket.send(packet);
    }

    }
```

```
    public class UDP_Client {

    public static DatagramSocket socket;
    static InetAddress address;
    public static DatagramPacket packet;

    public static void main(String args[]){


    final int puerto = 3000;

    try{   

    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

    byte[] buf = payload.MSG.getBytes();
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address , puerto);

    while(true){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new enviar(), 0, 50);
    }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
    }
```

Thanks mates!!

Comment: try `UDP_Client.socket` instead of `socket` in the method `run()`

Comment: To access a static in another class qualify with the class name (like `UDP_Client.socket`). Ideally, avoid global state and pass the instance around as a parameter, though (`new enviar(socket, packet)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not telling Java where to find the `socket` and `packet` fields. If you specify the class that contains them, it will resolve your issue. Your code should look something like this:

```java
UDP_Client.socket.send(UDP_Client.packet);
```

This will work, but you can also statically import the fields, in the `enviar` file, so that you don't need the class name identifier.

```java
import static package.to.UDP_Client.socket;
import static package.to.UDP_Client.packet;
```

Then you could just leave your code as-is.